# Homeomorphism preserving open subsets of two different topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

If I have a Topological space $X=X_1\times X_2$, and $E_1\subset X_1$ is closed.

Considering the function $f_y : X_1\mapsto X$ by $f_y(x)=(x,y)$. This is a homeomorphism from between $E_1$ and $E_1\times\{y\}$. So from this can we also conclude that $E_1\times \{y\}\subset X_1\times X_2$ is a closed subset?

Comment: We can't, unless points are closed in $X_2$

Comment: What part of my reasoning fails? I know that if $A\subset X_1$ is closed and $B\subset X_2$ is closed, then $A\times B\subset X_1\times X_2$ is closed, but what if $U\subset X_1$ is open, $f\colon X_1 \mapsto X$ is an open map. Should $f(U)\subset X$ be open? When does a homeomorphism preserve openness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homeomorphism preserves openness, and preserves closedness too. But it does this in spaces between which it establishes a correspondence. So in your case, $E_1 \times \{y\}$ is surely a closed subset of the **subspace topology** on $X_1 \times \{y\}$ induced by the topology on $X_1 \times X_2$, but $E_1 \times \{y\}$ doesn't have to be a closed subset of $X_1 \times X_2$ itself.

Consider the case when $X_2$ is the trivial topology. Which sets are closed in $X_1 \times X_2$ then?